# Deeplinking with a domain name

Tags: ios, react-native, react-navigation, deep-linking

I have the following code in my `App.js`:

```js
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import { SafeAreaView, Text } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer, useLinking } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();
const Screen1 = () => <SafeAreaView><Text>Screen1</Text></SafeAreaView>;
const Screen2 = () => <SafeAreaView><Text>Screen2</Text></SafeAreaView>;

export default function App() {
  const ref = useRef();
  const [isReady, setIsReady] = useState(false);
  const [initialState, setInitialState] = useState();
  const { getInitialState } = useLinking(ref, {
    prefixes: ['http://example.com', 'mychat://'],
    config: {
      screens: {
        Screen2: 'screen-2',
      },
    },
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    getInitialState().then((state) => {
      if (state !== undefined) setInitialState(state);

      setIsReady(true);
    });
  }, [getInitialState]);

  if (!isReady) return null;

  return (
    <NavigationContainer ref={ref} initialState={initialState}>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name='Screen1' component={Screen1} />
        <Stack.Screen name='Screen2' component={Screen2} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Most of them are copied from https://reactnavigation.org/docs/deep-linking/ and https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-linking/.

In the docs there is `prefixes: ['https://mychat.com', 'mychat://']`, I just changed `https://mychat.com` to `http://example.com`. But it doesn't seem to work.

When I open the following links in Safari:

- `mychat://` (works, gets redirected to app **Screen1**)
- `mychat://screen-2` (works, gets redirected to app **Screen2**)
- `http://example.com` (just opens the link in the browser, no popup to redirect to app)

What change do I need to make to redirect the domain name to the mobile app? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a domain that you have access to alongside a server.

Your server needs to host a couple of files, typically within the `.well-known` directory:

- `apple-app-site-association` (note the `.json` is not needed)
- `assetlinks.json`

You also need to enable some entitlements within your app for iOS, this may also be true for Android. On iOS, this will be enabling the *Associated Domains* entitlement alongside an entry for `webcredentials:yourdomain.com`

The documentation is pretty good to go through to give an understanding on what needs to be done in order to achieve Universal Links

- https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html
- https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-site-associations

Examples:

- iOS - https://stackoverflow.com/.well-known/apple-app-site-association
- Android - https://stackoverflow.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json

Comment: I guess `appID` and `sha256_cert_fingerprints` will only be generated when you publish your app to App Store and Google Play?

Comment: You would use your app release keystore to generate the fingerprint. As for `appID` this is your team id (from the Apple Developer console) with a dot, then your bundle identifier. `123.com.my.app`.